# ExtJS: Second Modal Window causing error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addCls' of null

Tags: extjs, extjs4.1

I am getting the error: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addCls' of null" in the following scenario.

I have a requirement of two modal windows. The first modal window has a Grid. When I double click on the Grid in the first modal window, I should open a second modal window. Below is the code I used:

```
  saleOrderEmployeeGrid.on('celldblclick', function(tableview, td, cellIndex, record, tr, rowIndex, e, eOpts){
    loadActivityWindow();
  });
  }

  function loadActivityWindow()
  {
        jobSlotActivityWin = new Ext.Window({
        id          :'jobSlotActivityWinId',
        modal       : true,
        layout      : 'fit',
        width       : 900,
        height      : 500,
        closeAction :'destroy',
        plain       : true,
        model       : true,
        stateful    : false,
        title       :'Create Job Slot',
        items       : [soActivityPanel],
        buttons     : [{
            text        : 'Close',
            handler     : function(){
                            jobSlotActivityWin.destroy();
                        }
            }
        ] 
        });
        jobSlotActivityWin.show();
        Ext.WindowManager.register (createJobSlotWin); // createJobSlotWin is the first modal window
        Ext.WindowManager.register(jobSlotActivityWin); // jobSlotActivityWin is the second modal window created above
        Ext.WindowManager.bringToFront ('jobSlotActivityWinId');
  }
```

So, when I double click on the saleOrderEmployeeGrid, I see the second modal window fine. Then I close the second modal window and double click on the grid again on the first modal window.

This now doesn't bring up the second modal window. It completely goes masked and blank in the background of first modal window and I see the below error in the JavaScript Console:
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addCls' of null

To be more precise, the error seems to be coming out of jobSlotActivityWin.show() as my debug logs failed at that point.

Anyone faced this before and can help me?

Answer (score 8):

Set the closeAction to hide, not sure why the default is destroy but what it essentially means is that when the window is closed the element will be removed from the dom and `show` will not work anymore.

http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.panel.Panel-cfg-closeAction

reply to comments:

conditional create example

```
//the window is only created once, the data is always show and updated.

if(!this.win) {
    this.win = createWindow();
}

updateWindowData();
this.win.show();
```

Instead of saying closeAction:'hide' everywhere, we have something like this in our source

```
Ext.override(Ext.Window, {
    closeAction: 'hide'
})
```

If you put that snippet before any windows are created all of them will be closeAction hide by default.

Comment: Hey pllee, but everytime I am double clicking the grid, the function loadActivityWindow() creates the modal window again right? Wouldn't that bring the modal window element back into DOM?

Comment: However, I have gone ahead and tried 'hide' and it didn't work either. There is may be something fundamentally wrong in what I am doing !!

Comment: @rajugaadu   Yeah it won't work cause your handler is directly calling `destroy`.  It should be calling `close` instead.  Also globals, hard coded id's and blind creation without checking if a window exists is bad.  `new Window, new Window` with the same id's will throw an error I believe.

Comment: @rajugaadu conditionally creating and taking out the `destroy` "should " solve the problems you are seeing.

Comment: I have tried two of the things you suggested and it has 'partly' fixed the issue or rather postponed the issue i.e now when i close both modal windows and begin from the base page and double click on 1st modal, i see the same issue again.

Comment: I dynamically generated id and also used close instead of destroy. 

1. I would like more clarity on conditional creating. Basically each time I click on one row of the grid in the first modal. So, the second modal that I generate ideally will have different data depending on the row I double clicked on. What should the conditional check do?

2. Also, doesn't close() still keep the instance of modal window alive? Wouldn't that be a risk. Please pardon if my questions are too basic ... this is first time I am working on any JS framework.

Comment: @rajugaadu all Windows have to set closeAction to hide, the default is destroy.  The window should only get created once but the data should be updated every time.  I'll put an extra code snippet to show what I am talking about.  Keeping the instance alive is not any more of a risk than anything else that can be done on the client.  It is the preferred way, it is much more efficient.

Comment: Keep it coming :) While you help me with the snippet, am trying the closeAction to hide for both the modal windows.

Comment: @rajugaadu  Take out all of the code that has closeAction in it and place the `Ext.Override` snippet at the "top" of your code, before any windows are created.

Comment: Thank you for the snippet plleee. So, basically I have an if condition: if ( !jobSlotActivityWin ) before creating the Window. But this approaach started throwing me the same error that I reported. I should tell you one more thing, the moment I changed destroy() to close() and closeAction to hide on the 1st modal window, things started going wrong on it. I don't want to deny your concept as it has worked fine on the second modal window. Interestingly, one of my colleagues who has a simiar requirement ( he clicks on a button on first modal ), he is doing fine with destroy(s) !!!

Comment: He doesn't even register the windows to Ext.WindowMgr or bringToFront and still the modal windows don't conflict or mess up. I doing something perculiarly wrong here. Surely it has got to do with managing the windows that I am creating one after another on each double click. 

pllee ... I will try more today and post an update. Would you mind revisiting this post sometime tomorrow and help me if I need any further guidance?

Comment: @rajugaadu The last 3 lines about the WindowManager do not and should not be used, Ext should be handling that.

Answer (score 1):

set

```
   closeAction:'hide',
   onEsc: funtion() {
       jobSlotActivityWin.hide()
   }
```